# Auto-resizing images to fit page and creating new pages

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of 12 images that I would like to display on the screen, however I would like to cap the number of images that can fit onto the screen at 9, with the user having to swipe left to see the remaining 3 images.

I have currently hardcoded it, but I would like to know if there is a way to write it such that a maximum of 9 images will automatically resize themselves to fit onto the page, with future images being shown on the next screen, which the user can swipe to.

e.g. In the future if I have 25 images, first 9 will fit themselves onto the first screen, user can swipe to the second screen to see the next 9 and user can swipe again to see the last 7 - without hardcoding 9, 9, 7 per screen respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a screen that takes the list of images to be shown and the starting number in that list.

Images can be shown with a GridView Widget.

So for your example of 25 images:

ShowImagesScreen([image1, image2 ... image25], 0) will show the screen with the first 9 images, the 0 indicates that the screens starts with the first image (index 0 in the list). Swiping on that page will result in going to the next screen. Which is the same screen widget:

ShowImagesScreen([image1, image2 ... image25], 9) this time showing image 9 till 18. Swiping on this screen can go to previous page or to the next:

ShowImagesScreen([image1, image2 ... image25], 18)

On the screen you make logic to disable swiping back or forward when it is the first or last page respectively. You also need to check the length of the list on each page and check whether you are at the end.